# AP BC Calculus 2001 Part 1d: finding position given parametric derivatives.

Tags: calculus

Given: an object moves along a curve in the $xy$-plane with position $(x(t), y(t))$ at time $t$.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\cos(t^3) \text{ and } \frac{dy}{dt}=3\sin(t^2)$$

for $0 \leq t \leq 3$. At time $t=2$, the position is $(4,5)$.

It then asks me what the position is at time $t=3$. This particular problem allows the use of graphing calculators, which determine derivatives and definite integrals. I know I have to determine the $x$ and $y$ coordinates independently, so I do the following:

$$dx=\cos(t^3) \space dt$$

And then I get stuck, because I know I am supposed to integrate both sides, but I am not sure how to do the right side. For answers, please don't explain how to integrate $\cos(t^3)$ generically, because the point is you are supposed to be able to do it without having to do this extra step. How do I determine the answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to notice that 
$$x(t)=4+\int_2^{t}\cos(s^3)\,\mathrm{d}s\\
  y(t)=5+3\int_2^{t}\sin(s^2)\,\mathrm{d}s\\$$
satisfy your equations. From there substitute $t=3$ and let your calculator compute the integrals.

Comment: How did you get these equations??? (i''m excited because I think I almost understand!)

Comment: Also, what does the integral portion intuitively represent? Is it the change in position from t=2?

Comment: Well for the first one (the second is the same idea), we need $\frac{dx}{dt}=\cos(t^3)$, which the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that can be satisfied by $x(t)=\int\limits_a^x\cos(s^3)\,\mathrm{d}s$. Now adding a constant or changing $a$ won't affect the derivative so we can pick convenient values. $a=2$ makes sure the integral is $0$ when $t=2$, and a constant of $4$ makes sure it satisfies $x(2)=4$.

Comment: Ohhhhh...... that makes total sense. Thank you!

Comment: Intuitively, the constants and lower bounds allow you to define a starting point. The integral part represents a sum of the speeds as you move. If $t=3$, (in the x direction) move a little bit at a speed of $x'(2)$, then a little bit at a speed of $x'(2.01)$, then a little bit at $x'(2.02)$, and so on gives an approximation of how much you've moved. The integral is a way of summing infinitely many tiny "little bits" together.

Comment: In fact, the integral symbol is an elongated s. It stands for sum!

Comment: Does this mean that there are multiple values of a and C?

Comment: If you think about it they are really the same operation (find $a$ such that $\int\limits_{a}^2\cos(s^3) \,\mathrm{d}s=4$, and you can write the first as one integral with no constant. With that being said, ignoring rewriting as I just did, the initial bounds do force these constants to be particular values.

Comment: Intuitively, if I only tell you how fast I'm going, but not where I start from, you know how much farther from where I started I end up, but you won't know exactly where I end up. If I do tell you where I start, you can now exactly where I end up at.

Answer (score 2):

you are on the right track. integrate $$dx = \cos(t^3)\, dt\text{ from $t = 2, x = 4$ to $t = 3, x$ }$$ that gives you $$x - 4 = \int_2^3\cos(t^3) \, dt \to x = 4 + \int_2^3\cos(t^3) \, dt = 4 + FnInt(\cos(x^3),x, 2, 3). $$

p.s. don't try integrating $\int\cos(t^3) \, dt$ by hand. there is not a closed form for this integral.

Comment: 1. Where did you get the sin(t^3) from?
2. Where did you get the limits of integration?
3. Where did you get the x - 4 from?

Comment: @louiemcconnell, typo. is fixed now.

Comment: I'm still lost for #2 and #3

Comment: @louiemcconnell, i got the initial condition from the position vector $(4,5)$ at time $t = 2.$  the limits of integration is from $2$ to $3,$ because you are interested in finding the position at $t = 3.$

Comment: @louiemcconnell, you must be taking the ap exam next month?

Comment: yes... this particular topic is troubling, because I am having great difficulty finding resources for this topic :/

Comment: @louiemcconnell, there are plenty of old exams and their solution on the ap website. every year, the problems are almost similar to previous years'. practice the problems. the problem you posted comes under the category net change theorem: $Q(t_1) -Q(t_0) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \frac{dQ}{dt} dt.$  the same comes under the separation of variables later on in the differential equation.  good luck with the exam.